# Left join in SQL to identify certain rows

Tags: mysql, sql, merge, left-join

Given below is table A:

| Cust_id | Code |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 101 |
| 1 | 102 |
| 1 | 103 |
| 2 | 201 |

Table B:

| Cust_id | Code |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 101 |
| 1 | 102 |

Table B has only customer 1 and contains only two product codes of customer 1.
I want to identify the code of customers in Table B that is not present in Table B.

| Cust_id | Code |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 103 |

To get this, I did Table A left join Table B on cust_id and code and thought those with null values of code in Table B would give the desired result, but it did not seem to work. It would be really helpful if someone could tell what should the correct steps be. Thanks

My query so far:

```
select a.cust_id, a.code, b.cust_id as customer, b.code as product 
from a 
left join b on a.cust_id = b.cust_id and a.code = b.code
```

Comment: `create table final as select a.cust_id, a.code, b.cust_id as customer, b.code as product from a left join b on a.cust_id = b.cust_id and a.code=b.code` 

After this, I queried rows where customer is not null and product is null.

Comment: The main problem is that there are two conditions (see my answer on this), but with a left join you are applying just one condition. It is possible to work with an outer join, but it won't get readable. The appropriate oparators for lookups are `[NOT] EXISTS` and `[NOT] IN`, not joins.

Comment: Your expected result has two columns, but your query selects four columns. Do you want twq or four?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two conditions:

- cust_id must be in table B
- (cust_id, code) must not be in table B

The query with the conditions almost literally translated from human language to SQL:

```
select *
from a
where cust_id in (select cust_id from b)
and (cust_id, code) not in (select cust_id, code from b);
```

Answer (score 0):

- List item
- Hello other solution using exists

```
select a.cust_id, a.code
  from TABLEA a  left   join TABLEB  b on 
      a.cust_id=b.cust_id and a.code=b.code
 where b.cust_id is null and exists( select * from TABLEB 
      where cust_id=a.cust_id)
```